# When I switch to xfce4 desktop, my login credentials don't work until I switch back

Tags: login, xfce, login-screen, 21.04

Installed the xfce4 desktop environment, logged out, did the desktop environment switch, now I can't login. How do I get xfce to recognize my login?

Comment: Details on what packages you added may help; did you add `xubuntu-desktop` or something else?   If something-else, did you install all packages needed?  I'd also suggest you check you have space in $HOME (your user directory) as a GUI login cannot occur if insufficient space exists for work files to be created.

Comment: I did install xubuntu-desktop and I have plenty of space in my user directory.

Comment: Are you selecting Xubuntu/XFCE at the DM/greeter screen?  (ie. telling the DM which desktop session you want to use?)  Which DM did you select to use?  (An initially Ubuntu Desktop install will mean `gdm3` was default; adding `xubuntu-desktop` will cause `lightdm` to be added and you would have been asked which to use; this controls how you select the desktop at login)

Comment: I'm selecting xfce via the "cog" on the gnome login screen. It shows gnome, xfce are available. So do I need to install gdm3? Just checked it is still installed so I guess I need to change the default DM?

Comment: No you shouldn't need to switch to using `lightdm`... I don't have a handy box to test; but I'm sure it's possible (its just not as easy to find on `gdm3` but I think you've found it already from your wording). As already stated I'd check sufficient space is available in /home (particularly $HOME) but you've done that already you stated.